# Svg Icon color in FloatingActionButton

Tags: material-ui

This used to work fine in material-ui 0.14.8 but not in 0.15.4:

```
import FloatingActionButton from 'material-ui/FloatingActionButton';
import MyLocation from 'material-ui/svg-icons/maps/my-location';

<FloatingActionButton>
  <MyLocation color={color} />
</FloatingActionButton>
```

The color is not taken into account anymore. Why?

Answer (score 5):

Okay found a way to achieve the same with iconStyle:

```
<FloatingActionButton iconStyle={{fill: 'red'}}>
  <MyLocation />
</FloatingActionButton>
```

Comment: Yep, the developers want the Button to control the Icon's color, but unfortunatelly they didn't state that clearly in the documentation. [link](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/3847)